# How can I seek in a buffer? C

Tags: c, string, parsing

I have a buffer that is text read from a file. I loop over it like so to count the lines:

```
    while(fgets(buf, 1024, fp) != NULL){

        for(counter = strtok(buf,"\n"); counter; counter=strtok(0,"\n")){               
            threads++;
        }  
    }

    printf("NUMBER OF THREADS: %i", threads);
```

and then I loop over it again to parse each line and start a thread with the parameters parsed in that line.

When I run this, though, it exits because the next line is:

```
while(fgets(buf, 1024, fp) != NULL){
 ....
}
```

and I suppose it's because fgets is looking at the end of the buffer.

Can I seek back to the beginning of the buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `rewind(fp);` or `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);`

`fseek` is considered better practice since it returns a status code.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should not be using [strtok](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok.html) as it cannot be interleaved, even without threads, and with threads you're just asking for trouble. It sounds like you are incrementing your buffer variable somewhere. Just keep around the original buffer variable and modify a copy, and then you should be golden.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with the term "interleaved" -- what do you mean? I'm using strtok just to break up the lines, and then I parse them with sscanf and pass those to the various threads.

Comment: You think I might run into problems? Here's the general flow of things: I create 4 buffers, parse the URL, and pass those to a thread -- then in that thread, the first thing I do is allocate memory for those strings and keep them within the function.

Comment: Interleaved means doing one thing then the other. Yes, you still might run into issues, because strtok modifies a global variable to maintain its state. It is innately thread hostile. There is a threadsafe alternative called "strtok_r", but it's really best to avoid that beast altogether, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

keep another pointer that only points to the beginning of the buffer (`char * begin` perhaps?), then reinitialize fp after the first while loop. this will effectively "seek" back to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `fgets()` will read one line at a time, so there will be at most one newline in the string that it returns.

Note that `strtok()` modifies the string that it scans, putting NUL characters into the original string at the end of each token.

Either or both of these could be affecting your logic.